# django TypeError expected string or buffer

Tags: django, date

I have a view :

```
def TakeAppointmentView(request):
    appointment_date = request.GET.get('appointment_date',False)
    app = Appointment()
    app.appointment_date = appointment_date
    app.save()
```

I have model for Appointment. When I do this it gives the error saying 'expected string or buffer' but the date is being saved in the database. Saving in the database works fine but gives the error.

Whats wrong with this ??

```
class AppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    appointment_date = forms.DateField()

    def clean_appointment_date(self):
        appointment_date = self.cleaned_data['appointment_date']
        today = date.today()
        next_week = today + timedelta(days=7)
        if appointment_date is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must provide a date to take appointment")
        if appointment_date < today:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You cannot take appointment on past date")
        if appointment_date > next_week:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You can only take appointment with in one week")
    return appointment_date
```

Also the form is not being validated.. It dont show any error message if doesnt match the validation..

Its kicking my ass ...

Any Help??

Comment: Why are you using `False`?

Comment: incase the date is not provided...

Comment: But what is it supposed to do/mean?

Comment: @Aaeronn If there's no date provided, wouldn't `None` be more appropriate?

Comment: when I removed False then its saying "None value has invalid date format".. Now whats that ??

Comment: I have edited my question with form